# Why is my question closed when it already has enough details?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Which EMF frequencies have the most spread and permeability?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/561800/which-emf-frequencies-have-the-most-spread-and-permeability)

It has enough details and I explained that to a user in the comments,  operative word is "generally". That user was trolling, you are engaging in the same kind of trolling by closing the thread.

Comment: Do note that verbally abusing other users will get you nowhere. As a general advice, when you bring something to Meta, you should come with the intention of learning about site policies rather than blaming and disrespecting other site users.

Comment: I find it odd that you accused someone of trolling, but didn't even bother to try to answer their question before assuming that they were a troll and not serious.

Comment: Yeah lemme insist on this: the kind of language in the original post is *completely* unacceptable.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the close voters that your question is unclear, and I've elaborated in a comment there.

If you believe another user is behaving in a way that violates our community standards, you should use the flagging system to bring the situation to the attention of the [diamond moderators](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), which include me. I have to say that there is no evidence from your question or its comments (deleted or extant) that you have been the victim of any "trolling," disingenuousness, or even impoliteness.

We'd love to help answer your question; we just don't yet understand what your question is.